# getting error for kitchen create in chef

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, chef-infra, virtualization, test-kitchen

As i am very new to chef i am not able to figure out following error :

```
$ kitchen create
-----> Starting Kitchen (v1.4.2)
>>>>>> ------Exception-------
>>>>>> Class: Kitchen::UserError
>>>>>> Message: Error parsing /home/ashishk/motd/.kitchen.yml as YAML.
Please run `kitchen diagnose --no-instances --loader' to help debug your issue.
>>>>>> ----------------------
>>>>>> Please see .kitchen/logs/kitchen.log for more details
>>>>>> Also try running `kitchen diagnose --all` for configuration
```

My .kitchen.yml file looks like :

```
$ cat .kitchen.yml
---
driver:
  name: vagrant
    provisioner:
#  name: policyfile_zero
  name: chef_zero
platforms:
  - name: ubuntu-14.04
#  - name: centos-7.1
driver:
      customize:
        memory: 256

suites:
  - name: default
        run_list:
                - recipe[motd::default]
    attributes:
```

I am following the doc [https://learn.chef.io/local-development/ubuntu/get-started-with-test-kitchen/][1]

Please help me what is wrong here !

Installed Vagrant now getting following error :

```
 VirtualBox is complaining that the installation is incomplete. Please
       run `VBoxManage --version` to see the error message which should contain
>>>>>> ------Exception-------
>>>>>> Class: Kitchen::ActionFailed
>>>>>> Message: Failed to complete #create action: [Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of vagrant up --no-provision --provider virtualbox ----
STDOUT:
STDERR: The provider 'virtualbox' that was requested to back the machine
'default' is reporting that it isn't usable on this system. The
reason is shown below:

VirtualBox is complaining that the installation is incomplete. Please
run `VBoxManage --version` to see the error message which should contain
instructions on how to fix this error.
---- End output of vagrant up --no-provision --provider virtualbox ----
Ran vagrant up --no-provision --provider virtualbox returned 1]
>>>>>> ----------------------
>>>>>> Please see .kitchen/logs/kitchen.log for more details
>>>>>> Also try running `kitchen diagnose --all` for configuration
```

Commandd : 
ashishk@chef-workstation:~/motd$ VBoxManage --version

```
WARNING: The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist.
         Please install the virtualbox-dkms package and the appropriate
         headers, most likely linux-headers-generic.

         You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
4.3.10_Ubuntur93012
```

Ps : 
I have Installed Virtual box on Windows 7 in that VM (ubuntu) I have chef workstation running "kitchen create" on it

Comment: Keep an eye on indentation. It starts below `driver` that this is screwed up. Whitespaces do matter.

Comment: Ok thanks that worked but now its giving error $ kitchen list
>>>>>> ------Exception-------
>>>>>> Class: Kitchen::UserError
>>>>>> Message: Vagrant 1.1.0 or higher is not installed. Please download a package from http://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html.
>>>>>> ----------------------
>>>>>> Please see .kitchen/logs/kitchen.log for more details
>>>>>> Also try running `kitchen diagnose --all` for configuration

Comment: I am using Ubuntu VM as workstation so vagrant should be installed on that VM or on Base machine ?

Comment: Vagrant has to be installed there, where VirtualBox is available.

Comment: Installed Vagrant now getting following error :  VirtualBox is complaining that the installation is incomplete. Please
       run `VBoxManage --version` to see the error message which should contain
>>>>>> ------Exception-------
>>>>>> Class: Kitchen::ActionFailed
>>>>>> Message: Failed to complete #create action: [Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of vagrant up --no-provision --provider virtualbox ----
STDOUT:
STDERR: The provider 'virtualbox' that was requested to back the machine

Comment: 'default' is reporting that it isn't usable on this system. The
reason is shown below:

VirtualBox is complaining that the installation is incomplete. Please
run `VBoxManage --version` to see the error message which should contain
instructions on how to fix this error.
---- End output of vagrant up --no-provision --provider virtualbox ----
Ran vagrant up --no-provision --provider virtualbox returned 1]
>>>>>> ----------------------
>>>>>> Please see .kitchen/logs/kitchen.log for more details
>>>>>> Also try running `kitchen diagnose --all` for configuration

Comment: ashishk@chef-workstation:~/motd$ VBoxManage --version
WARNING: The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist.
         Please install the virtualbox-dkms package and the appropriate
         headers, most likely linux-headers-generic.

         You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
4.3.10_Ubuntur93012

Comment: So did you install the kernel module as advised?

Comment: "virtualbox-dkms" installed but still giving error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have really make progress on the setup and deployment of "Chefdk 0.9.0. I went back and cleaned up all of my Path variable in User, System, Powershell's $PROFILE. I have been working on the chefdk installation for Windows 7 & 10 for a while, I found some interesting points to note:

1. If you have uninstalled and reinstalled chekdk, vagrant, and virtualbox, then    you must clean up the User, System, $Powershell's $Profile paths, or you will spend hours troubleshoot ghost.
2. White spaces does matter in the .kitchen.yml.  This was the only problem I did not face until today.  Thanks for the hint about the "driver:" above.
3. Install Vagrant last after either Virtualbox or chefdk.
4. Make sure that path for chefdk is in this order

   ```
     PATH="C:\opscode\chefdk\bin\;C:\opscode\chefdk\embedded\bin
   ```
5. Check your path for HOME, and CHEFDK_HOME.

After these few things everything should work fine.

---

```
 Windows 10 
 Chef Development Kit Version: 0.9.0 
 chef-client version: 12.5.1 
 berks version: 4.0.1 
 kitchen version: 1.4.2
```

Path in $PROFILE

$env:PATH="C:\opscode\chefdk\bin\;C:\opscode\chefdk\embedded\bin;C:\opscode\chefdk\modules\chef;C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox;C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.0\bin;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\bin;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Acronis\SnapAPI\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intuit\QBPOSSDKRuntime;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Puppet Labs\Puppet Enterprise\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\acquia-drupal7\common\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\acquia-drupal7\mysql\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\acquia-drupal7\php5_3\;C:\Program Files (x86)\acquia-drupal7\drush\;C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets\command;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\"

### >>"chef shell-init powershell | Invoke-Expression"<<

PS C:\Users\Preston 3rd (win 7)\chef-repo\kitchen> & "C:\Program       Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage" --version 
5.0.6r103037

PS C:\Users\Preston 3rd (win 7)\chef-repo\kitchen> vagrant --version 
Vagrant 1.7.4 
PS C:\Users\Preston 3rd (win 7)\chef-repo\kitchen>

```
 PS C:\Users\Preston 3rd (win 7)\chef-repo\kitchen> bundle install 
 Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.......... 
 Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/... 
 Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.. 
 Resolving dependencies... 
 Using ffi 1.9.10 
 Using win32-process 0.8.2 
 Using wmi-lite 1.0.0 
 Using mixlib-shellout 2.2.3 
 Using net-ssh 2.9.2 
 Using net-scp 1.2.1 
 Using safe_yaml 1.0.4 
 Using thor 0.19.1 
 Using test-kitchen 1.4.2 
 Using kitchen-vagrant 0.19.0 
 Using bundler 1.10.6 
 Bundle complete! 2 Gemfile dependencies, 11 gems now installed. 
 Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

---

```
 Preston Thornton
 skype: preston4life
 preston3271@gmail.com
```

Comment: I had spacing issue :-P. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread but it just got me so I wanted to share my issue.

Instead of using spaces to indent, I did a tab and that's what caused my parsing YAML error.

Answer (score 1):

Copying the below contents and replacing them with the existing kitchen.yml would resolve the problem:

```
driver:
  name: vagrant

provisioner:
  name: chef_zero

platforms:
  - name: ubuntu-14.04
    driver:
      customize:
        memory: 256

suites:
  - name: default
    run_list:
      - recipe[motd_ubuntu::default]
    attributes:
```